# jQuery code called from PHP won't execute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress site that (of course) is composed of multiple PHP templates. The particular template fragment I'm having problems with is called with this line:

```
<script id="templatehidden">                                    
    <?php get_template_part( 'fragments/calculator', 'row-sa' ); ?>
</script>
```

And the contents of calculator-row-sa.php  are:

```
<div class="form-row pricingrow select-multiple">
<div class="form-controls"> 
<img class="remove-field-sa" style="float: left; margin-right: 30px;" src="http://45.32.89.214/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/minus.png">
<i style="margin-left: 50px;" class="cardinal"></i>
    <select name="field-followers[]" class="select followerselect">
        <?php foreach ( $options as $option ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option[ 'value' ] ?>"><?php echo $option[ 'label' ] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <b class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #747474";></b>     
    <span class="acctprice"></span>
</div><!-- /.form-controls -->
```

And the jQuery code behind it is

```
$('.remove-field-sa').click(function () {           
        $(this).closest('.form-row').remove();
    });
```

My problem is with the img element inside the php. When the page first loads, it does its job and removes the row it's on. However, after I add more rows, no javascript code seems to execute within .form-content anymore. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are adding the rows using javascript, you need event delegation: At the moment you bind your even handler, the elements don't exist and when you add them, the `click` event is not automatically binded to these new elements unless you use event delegation.

You can easily change that using for example:

```
$('.form-content').on('click', '.remove-field-sa', function () {           
    $(this).closest('.form-row').remove();
});
```

Note that here the `.form-content` element has to be present on page-load. If it is not, you could also use something like:

```
// Any parent element that is present at page-load and will contain the child elements will do.
$('body').on('click', '.remove-field-sa', function () {           
    $(this).closest('.form-row').remove();
});
```

Comment: Nice. isn't the **delegate function** also possible? maybe just in case the jquery gets updated later on.

Comment: @baboizk Yes, but note that `on()` is not deprecated. Are you perhaps thinking of `live()`?

Comment: Yes, that's it ! *live()* got replaced by *on()*. apologies

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Looks like I've got a lot to learn about events, handlers and delegations, but at least, for now, it worked.